# Plastic SCM upgrade

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab, plasticscm

My company is currently using plastic scm version 4, and needs to upgrade to the newest version, 6, for the git features it provides,  what are some best practices for doing this? And what tips does anyone have for not breaking anything...  I'm an intern here for the summer and was tasked with researching it, but I can't see to find anything about going from 4 to 5.4.

The server is being run on windows server 2008 R2

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last available version is Plastic SCM 5.4.16.753

The upgrade process is very straightforward. You just need to run the installer and it will automatically upgrade the binaries and the databases. Just remember that you will need to upgrade the server and all the clients because 5.4 is not compatible with 4.

You can download the installers at www.plasticscm.com

Comment: Can I also trigger the update process manually? I am running PSCM as a portable application